# Is it possible to return outer method from inner method?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Is it possible to return outer method from inner method?

```
class TempProjectClass {

  void firstMethod(){
      secondMethod();
      Log.d("log","hello!"); 
  }

  void secondMethod(){
      return; // Than, I dont want to see log message "hello!".
  }
}
```

I want to make secondMethod able to finish firstMethod.
Is there no way I make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly.

You can return a value from the inner method indicating that the outer method should return, and check that in the outer method:

```
  void firstMethod(){
      if (secondMethod()) return;
      Log.d("log","hello!"); 
  }

  boolean secondMethod(){
      return true; // Than, I dont want to see log message "hello!".
  }
```